# Java: Font not showing in new window

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and as such I've been doing my own small projects to help my learning. The code below when run will launch a new window where I changed the colour background which is correct, but the text doesn't appear and I don't understand why as there are no error messages. 
In trying to fix this I tried it as an applet instead of a frame but that failed to work due to an error with a missing class. My guess is I'm missing something here but I don't know what.
Any help appreciated

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Fonts extends Frame
{

   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      setBackground(Color.blue);
      g.setColor(Color.white);
      Font quote = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 30);
      g.setFont(quote);
      g.drawString("Hello World ", 10, 10);

   }

   public static void main (String args[])
   {
      Frame ff = new Fonts();
      ff.resize(500,500);
      ff.show();

   }
}
```

Comment: The X and Y coordinates you pass to `g.drawString` are the coordinates of the *baseline* of the text—that is, the bottom of each English letter.  Try `10, 100` instead of `10, 10`.

Comment: Many thanks for that. It solved the problem. I hadn't realised it was the coordinates of the baseline. Much appreciated